# How can I cast a string with scientific notation to a decimal in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Say I have a column of strings with a Unix nano format (e.g. 1.60619194118981E+018). What is the best way to convert this to an integer using BigQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can cast it to `NUMERIC` type.

```sql
SELECT CAST('1.60619194118981E+018' AS NUMERIC) 

+---------------------+
|         f0_         |
+---------------------+
| 1606191941189810000 |
+---------------------+
```

[image]